# Set both Parent and Child item as "Selected" in asp:Menu

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

So i am trying to do the following in order to style (StaticSelectedStyle-CssClass and DynamicSelectedStyle-CssClass) the selected child item AND its parent. The following code causes only the parent to style:

```
  private bool SetSelectedMenuItem(MenuItemCollection menuItems)
    {
        foreach (MenuItem item in menuItems)
        {
            string url = ResolveUrl(item.NavigateUrl);
            string pageUrl = Request.RawUrl;
            if (pageUrl.Equals(url))
            {
                item.Selected = true;

                if (item.Parent != null)
                {
                    item.Parent.Selected = true;
                }
                return true;
            }

            if (SetSelectedMenuItem(item.ChildItems))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Is it even possible to have a child and its parent item to have their selected value set to true?

Any help to get this working would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. Take a look at [documentation on the Selected property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menuitem.selected(v=vs.110).aspx). The last line of the Remarks section says this:

> Only one menu item can be selected at a time in the Menu control.

Comment: Is there a different way to force the css class onto the parent item?

Comment: Maybe jQuery. If all you're doing with this postback is setting styles, that might be the better option anyway.